# parsing RAW data from sensor in php

Tags: php, parsing, temperature, raw-data

I am getting data from sensor as below.

```
array (
    'timestamp' => '2020-06-11T11:09:21.335Z',
    'type' => 'Unknown',
    'mac' => 'F64BB46181EF',
    'bleName' => 'P RHT 900350',
    'rssi' => -63,
    'rawData' => '02010605166E2AC90A04166F2A240D09502052485420393030333530',
  )
```

and i am trying to decode the RAW data with various PHP function

**ORD , CHAR , UNPACK , PACK**
I have tried many things but i only get the device name from the parsed data

which is **P RHT 900350**. So how can i extract the temperature and humidity data from this RAW data.

The sensor support team pass me the document to understand the structure. but i dint get through it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The values are hexadecimal.

Use `$values = str_split($array['rawData'] , 2 );` to get the values per key. (note, other than in the excel, arrays start with key `0`)

The humidity is easy: just convert from hex to decimal

`$humidity = hexdec($values[13]); //gives 36`

**LSB** and **MSB** stand for *least significant bit* and *most significant bit*  [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering) or [byte](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/most-significant-bit-or-byte)

The solution is to combine them (MSB + LSB) and convert to decimal:

```
$x = $values[8].$values[7]; //gives 0AC9
$c = hexdec($x);    //gives 2761
$temp = $c/100;     //gives 27.61
```

Key `16 - 27` (the *nom's*) is the device name character by character, converted to hex. So

```
16 : hex 50 = dec 80 (in the ascii table, 80 = P)
17 : hex 20 = dec 32 (in the ascii table, 32 = space)
18 : hex 52 = dec 82 (in the ascii table, 82 = R)
etc
```

Comment: it's actually `significant byte`, not `significant bit` in this case.

Comment: @Nick So how can we consider a temperature in minus

Comment: @Michel It gives me wrong value if the temp is in minus. "02010605166E2AB4FA04166F2A310D09502052485420393030333531" the support suggested me to *You have to do a 2 complement, which is reversing all the bits, and add 1 in binary.*